# Android Emulator does not load even after HAX working and loading from snapshot

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio

I just installed the Android Studio version 1.0 RC4.

I've created a new emulator with following details

```
Name: Nexus_S_API_21

CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)

Path: /Users/anthony/.android/avd/Nexus_S_API_21.avd

Target: Google APIs (API level 21)

Skin: nexus_s

SD Card: 100M

Snapshot: yes

hw.lcd.density: 240

hw.dPad: no

avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8

hw.camera.back: none

disk.dataPartition.size: 200M

hw.gpu.enabled: no

runtime.network.latency: none

skin.dynamic: no

hw.keyboard: yes

runtime.network.speed: full

hw.device.hash2: MD5:e4aa1843c1036cf7c41ef163fc4d1028

hw.ramSize: 1534

tag.id: google_apis

tag.display: Google APIs

hw.sdCard: yes

hw.device.manufacturer: Google

hw.mainKeys: yes

hw.accelerometer: yes

hw.trackBall: no

hw.device.name: Nexus S

hw.sensors.proximity: yes

hw.battery: no

AvdId: Nexus_S_API_21

hw.sensors.orientation: yes

hw.audioInput: yes

hw.camera.front: none

hw.gps: yes

avd.ini.displayname: Nexus S API 21

snapshot.present: yes

vm.heapSize: 32

runtime.scalefactor: auto
```

However, all I see is the android loading screen. The actual phone doesn't load up.

This is what I see in the Run window

```
/Users/anthony/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_S_API_21
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
```

This has been going on for last 20 minutes. It can't possibly take that long, can it?...

[image]

Comment: I had got the same problem, deleting and creating a new emulator fixed it.

Comment: I tried that but the result is the same. ..

Comment: I have the same problem, I start the emulator (api 21) last night, it booting for 1 hour for no result.

Answer (score 0):

I also just upgraded to Android Studio 1.0 RC4. You might try going to the emulator directory and then running the  emulator command manually. I did this and found error messages that were not displayed in the Studio's run window. Although I had a different problem, the error messages were of help.

c:\your-path\emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_S_API_21